# Sending array of objects in form-data. Swagger, OpenAPI 3

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, multipartform-data, openapi

I am trying to send a form-data request which has an array of objects. The problem is that the data that I receive on my Express server comes in the form of an array in which all objects are turned into a string. I can't change anything in the server, I need to solve this problem using Swagger.

```
      "requestBody": {
     "content": {
         "multipart/form-data": {
            "schema": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                   "video[]": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                       "type": "object",
                       "properties": {
                          "_id": {
                             "type": "string"
                          }
                       }
                    },
                    "describtion": "Video ids "
                 }
               }
            },
            "encoding": {
               "video[]": {
                 "contentType": "application/json",
                 "explode": true
               }
            }
         }
     }
 },
```

What I expect on server: `{ video: [{ _id: "string" }] }`

What I get: `{ video: [ '{"_id": "string"}' ] }`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are not parsing the 'video' property. Try the below code in the controller function.

```
const {video} = req.body;
parsedVideo = JSON.parse(video);
console.log(parsedVideo);
```